# How to create automatic image gallery slideshow by using HTML,CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This isn't working, can anyone help?

I am trying to build a website where the images slide to the right. I have tried the solution from a previous post but that still didnt work.

```js
(function () {
    var imgLen = document.getElementById('imgGallary');
    var images = imgLen.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var counter = 1;

    if (counter <= images.length) {
        setInterval(function () {
            images[0].src = images[counter].src;
            console.log(images[counter].src);
            counter++;

            if (counter === images.length) {
                counter = 1;
            }
        }, 4000);
    }
})();
```

```css
 .container{
            position:relative;
            width:600px;
            height:330px;
            border-radius:5px;
            border:4px solid black;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin-left:320px;
        }
#imgGallary > img
{ 
  width:700px;
  height:330px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="imgGallary" class="container">
                <img src="image/lake-louise-51543_960_720.jpg" />
                <img src="image/snow-in-pine-tree-1265118__340.jpg" />
                <img src="image/winter-385640_960_720.jpg"/>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is the JavaScript in a script tag at the end of the body?

Comment: no its not in a script tag i'm making my website using visual studio 2015 where i have a JavaScript.js page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix the issue you're having with the first image not coming in correctly. Keep the HTML and CSS the same. Change the JavaScript. Here I use window.onload, but I think your self invoking method would work, too. As for sliding it to the right, the way you have things set up is very prohibitive. I tried creating a clone and sliding the clone, but there are conflicts that make it not worth while.

If you want to slide the image, I would actually go a different route. Rather than changing the src attribute, why don't you just stack the images on top of each other using absolute positioning and z-indexes? Then you can get rid of that overflow property and just apply the border to the image, or better yet set those images as div background images (ie. background: url('lake.jpg') center center no-repeat), that way you don't even have to worry about sizing them, and they won't get distorted. In CSS, give each div a transition of "transform 0.25s" (or something to that effect). Then you can just apply a transform to them in javascript to slide them to the right. To bring them back, simply get rid of the transition value and assign a transform value of 0 to the image, but make sure the z-index is lower than the currently displayed image. If you do go the transform route, remember to add your -ms- and -webkit- prefixes to be accessible to older browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Anyway, that's just one thought. Here's the code to fix your issue with loading the wrong image. By the way, I would consider using jQuery next time for complicated css rulings (if you decide to go my route). Good luck!

JS

```
window.onload = function () {

    var imgLen = document.getElementById('imgGallary');
    var images = imgLen.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var counter = 1;

    //Store the src attributes in an array
    var src = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {   
        src[i] = images[i].src;
    }

    console.log(src);

    setInterval(function () {

        if (counter < images.length) {

            images[0].src = src[counter];
            console.log(src[counter]);
            counter++;


        }

        // Here we're saying if the counter is equal to the length of images, go back to the first images
        // and reset the counter.
        else {

            images[0].src = src[0];
            console.log(src[0]);
            counter = 1;

        }

        }, 4000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you assign a new `src` value to the first image tag, you can't get back the original `src` value of that tag.

You need to make an empty `img` tag withour `src` attribute, so that you can assign the src value to that tag.

```js
(function () {
    var imgLen = document.getElementById('imgGallary');
    var images = imgLen.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var counter = 1;

    if (counter <= images.length) {
        setInterval(function () {
            images[0].src = images[counter].src;
            console.log(images[counter].src);
            counter++;

            if (counter === images.length) {
                counter = 1;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
})();
```

```css
.container{
            position:relative;
            width:600px;
            height:330px;
            border-radius:5px;
            border:4px solid black;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin-left:320px;
        }
#imgGallary > img
{ 
  width:700px;
  height:330px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgGallary" class="container">
                <img />
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350?text=img1" />
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350?text=img2" />
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350?text=img3"/>
            </div>
```

Comment: Haha, why didn't I think of that? Still, though, sliding his images is tough the way things are currently set up.